# Modify react color picker design

Tags: reactjs, color-picker

Hi there i am using React color picker which type is Compact.
The problem is the default size is not according to me page design. so that i want to delete some part of the color picker .

[image: This the default color picker given bye react]

[image: The thing i want to cut]

[image: The final Result i want]

I want to cut the lower part. But i am unable to find the code or file from where i can modify this.

Comment: Check this link https://prereact.com/react-color-picker-npm-package/, it has many designs for the color-picker. Select the one you need and code it in your app. The code for the Compact you referred is there also.

Answer (score 0):

For Compact Picker you can adapt the following code to your app.

```
import React from 'react';
import { CompactPicker } from 'react-color';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      background: '#ecf1f5',
     }
  }
  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex});
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App ">
        <CompactPicker color={ this.state.background }onChange={ this.handleChangeComplete }/>
      </div>
    );}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the lower part using CSS.

Something like this should work:

```
.compact-picker .flexbox-fix {
   display: none;
}
```

N.B. *Please do check the class names in your app and put them appropriately. I have used mine by seeing from their online demo page.*